# How to reuse a created schema?

Tags: mysql, csv, dolphindb

Scenario:
Based on a created dfs table, the results are obtained using `loadTable("dfs://OLAP_STOCK", "snap").schema().colDefs`

[image]

Use the script to obtain the schema of a csv file:

```
filePath = "C:/data/2020/20200102/SH501000.csv"
fileSchema = extractTextSchema(filePath)
```

the fileSchema information is as follows:

[image]

Since the table has lots of columns, is there any way quickly generate vector expressions of name and type based on the information obtained above?

Answer (score 0):

Take csv file as an example, the code is:

```py
def getFileSchemaName(filePath){
    schema = extractTextSchema(filePath)
    name = string(NULL)
    for (i in schema.name){
        name = name + "`" + i
    }
    return name
}
def getFileSchemaType(filePath){
    schema = extractTextSchema(filePath)
    type = string(NULL)
    for (i in schema.type){
        type = type + "`" + i
    }
    return type
}

filePath = "C:/data/2020/20200102/test.csv"
name = getFileSchemaName(filePath)
type = getFileSchemaType(filePath)
```

name variable:

```py
`Symbol`DateTime`Status`PreClose`Open`High`Low`Price`TotalVolume`TotalAmount`AskPrice1`AskPrice2`AskPrice3`AskPrice4`AskPrice5`AskPrice6`AskPrice7`AskPrice8`AskPrice9`AskPrice10`BidPrice1`BidPrice2`BidPrice3`BidPrice4`BidPrice5`BidPrice6`BidPrice7`BidPrice8`BidPrice9`BidPrice10`AskVolume1`AskVolume2`AskVolume3`AskVolume4`AskVolume5`AskVolume6`AskVolume7`AskVolume8`AskVolume9`AskVolume10`BidVolume1`BidVolume2`BidVolume3`BidVolume4`BidVolume5`BidVolume6`BidVolume7`BidVolume8`BidVolume9`BidVolume10`TickCount`BidOrderTotalVolume`AskOrderTotalVolume`AvgBidOrderPrice`AvgAskOrderPrice`LimitHighestPrice`LimitLowestPrice
```

type variable:

```py
`SYMBOL`DATETIME`INT`DOUBLE`DOUBLE`DOUBLE`DOUBLE`DOUBLE`INT`DOUBLE`DOUBLE`DOUBLE`DOUBLE`DOUBLE`DOUBLE`DOUBLE`DOUBLE`DOUBLE`DOUBLE`DOUBLE`DOUBLE`DOUBLE`DOUBLE`DOUBLE`DOUBLE`DOUBLE`DOUBLE`DOUBLE`DOUBLE`DOUBLE`INT`INT`INT`INT`INT`INT`INT`INT`INT`INT`INT`INT`INT`INT`INT`INT`INT`INT`INT`INT`INT`INT`INT`DOUBLE`DOUBLE`DOUBLE`DOUBLE
```